# Is there any way to remove Duplicate Values From a Variable in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a Variable
Numbers=900354655,900354655,900354656

But I Want,
Numbers=900354655,900354656

Could you please help in this situation. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please pick either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, not both.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean by "values" in a variable. If you have a variable that contains a delimited **string** e.g. `"900354655,900354655,900354656"` then in XSLT 2.0 you can use the expression:

```
distinct-values(tokenize($yourVariable, ','))
```

to construct a **sequence** of distinct values (900354655, 900354656)